# How often is a commercial (airliner) flight flown without autopilot?

Tags: airliner, autopilot, aircraft-operations

When it comes to commercial flights, I am aware that once the aircraft has reached a certain altitude, the autopilot activates and assists the pilots in flying the aircraft. It makes being a pilot on a long flight a less tedious job.

But **what is the ratio of total flight hours to autopilot-flown hours** during a typical flight?

Comment: See: [When do pilots engage the autopilot in airliners?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16449/14897) and [On modern commercial airliners, how much of the flight could be fully taken care of by the auto pilot?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2866/14897)

Comment: Neither of those answers respond to his "how often" question directly.  The answer is, on a jet, pretty much every flight.  It's exhausting to have to hand fly a jet at cruise because it takes constant attention on the part of both pilots, one having to monitor the other pretty much full time, to avoid busting an altitude clearance.  With the AP on, only one pilot needs to monitor the AP and the other can do whatever they want, doze, read, go for a dump. And in any case, you need a working AP to fly in RVSM airspace.  If you want to fly with the AP inoperative, you are stuck below 29000 ft.

Comment: @JohnK: Stack Exchange is still working on improving the user-friendliness of the "banners", but note that "asker + community" means it's the asker that closed it on their own, I merely pointed to related topics. / @ FallenUser: If you wish to reopen it, I recommend adding to the body what is still missing for you that is not covered in either related posts, so the answers don't repeat anything.

Comment: Roger @ymb1 thanks.

Comment: Rephrased question in accordance to ymb1's suggestion.

Comment: @FallenUser: just a tip: there are "commercial" flights aren't flown in jets (a prop plane for hire), but I think you mean jetliners, so I recommend making that point clearer, use the tag [airliner] as well if that's what you mean.

Comment: @FallenUser: I just found this: [How much time is a commercial aircraft (e.g. A320 / B737NG families) flown manually?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26614/14897) :D don't hate me

Comment: I don't believe that question answers my main question. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: [Stefan's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/35244/14897) cites a paper that says 7 minutes are hand flown (which is about right), the rest is AP, the ratio will depend on how long the flight is.